# Rspec Not Failing on PG::GroupingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

Ruby: 2.1.8

Rails: 4.2.7

When I run a search on my Rails server, I put in a bad `group` statement in my query so that it would intentionally fail with a `PG::GroupingError`. When I run my tests, I don't receive this error, and my tests pass somehow. Here's what my test looks like:

```
it 'returns results' do
    get :index, search_params

    results_ids = assigns(:results).pluck(:id).uniq
    expect(results_ids).to eql([1, 2, 3])
end
```

Here's the code for my query:

```
address_ids = [1, 5, 7, 8, 10]

@results = User.includes(:address).references(:addresses).where(addresses: { id: address_ids })

filter_tags = true

if filter_tags
  @results = @results.joins('LEFT JOIN tags on tags.user_id = users.id').group('users.id').having('COUNT(tags) = ?', 0)
end
```

I've put a debugger in the test and have checked the value of `assigns(:results)`, and the tests failed afterwards, but they pass if I don't set the debugger.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the query?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I've added my code, @IgnacyKasperowicz.